# Asterisks instead of SMTP codes in response from Microsoft Exchange server

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server, swiftmailer

I'm working on a Laravel 4.2 application that needs to be able to send emails.  When the SwiftMailer component contacts the Microsoft Exchange server we use here it's receiving the following reply:

```
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
* BYE Connection is closed. 13
```

My understanding is that I *should* be seeing SMTP response codes 220 and 221 instead of those asterisks; the SwiftMailer module is throwing an Exception when it receives the message without the codes.

I'm trying to do some investigation before bugging my coworker who manages the server in question.  Does anybody have an idea how this substitution of asterisks for the codes may be occurring?  I'm confident based on reviewing the code in SwiftMailer than this isn't occurring to the text of the response after it's received.  Is this some sort of Exchange server security feature I'm unfamiliar with (and can't imagine the value of)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages indicate that you are  talking to an IMAP server, not an SMTP server. I'm  guessing you put the  wrong port number somewhere.

Comment: Excellent!  You're quite correct, I was using port 993, apparently typically used for IMAP.  I've switched to port 25, which we apparently use for this purpose, and got an actual useful error message.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Odds are that you've got an "intelligent" network device between you and the server that's doing traffic inspection. I've seen this with Cisco devices, where the SMTP connection banner is replaced with a string of asterisks and all the command words in the SMTP traffic are replaced with "XXXX".